# Py2neo IndexError: index out of range on Graph.run with gds.alpha.allShortestPaths.stream

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo, graph-data-science

I'm try to run `gds.alpha.allShortestPaths.stream` in a `py2neo.Graph` instance

That is my code:

```py
cypherCode = """CALL gds.alpha.allShortestPaths.stream({
nodeQuery: 'MATCH (n:AUTHOR) RETURN id(n) AS id',
relationshipQuery: 'MATCH (n:AUTHOR)-[r:COAUTHORS]-(p:AUTHOR) RETURN id(n) AS source, id(p) AS target'
})
YIELD sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, distance
return sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, distance
"""
r = graph.run(cypherCode)
```

I'm using `relationshipQuery: 'MATCH (n:AUTHOR)-[r:COAUTHORS]-(p:AUTHOR) RETURN id(n) AS source, id(p) AS target'` becouse I need undirected paths.

After 60sec I get this error:

```
IndexError: index out of range
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py in run(self, cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
    403         :return:
    404         """
--> 405         return self.auto().run(cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
    406 
    407     def evaluate(self, cypher, parameters=None, **kwparameters):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py in run(self, cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
    976                 result = self._connector.run(self.ref, cypher, parameters)
    977             else:
--> 978                 result = self._connector.auto_run(cypher, parameters,
    979                                                   graph_name=self.graph.name,
    980                                                   readonly=self.readonly)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/__init__.py in auto_run(self, cypher, parameters, pull, graph_name, readonly)
   1341             if pull != 0:
   1342                 try:
-> 1343                     cx.pull(result, n=pull)
   1344                 except TypeError:
   1345                     # If the RUN fails, so will the PULL, due to

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py in pull(self, result, n, capacity)
    941         result.append(response, final=(n == -1))
    942         try:
--> 943             self._sync(response)
    944         except BrokenWireError as error:
    945             result.transaction.mark_broken()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py in _sync(self, *responses)
    745         self.send()
    746         for response in responses:
--> 747             self._wait(response)
    748 
    749     def _audit(self, task):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py in _wait(self, response)
    740         """
    741         while not response.full() and not response.done():
--> 742             self._fetch()
    743 
    744     def _sync(self, *responses):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py in _fetch(self)
    715         failed state into an exception.
    716         """
--> 717         tag, fields = self.read_message()
    718         if tag == 0x70:
    719             self._responses.popleft().set_success(**fields[0])

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py in read_message(self)
    642 
    643     def read_message(self):
--> 644         tag, fields = self._reader.read_message()
    645         if tag == 0x71:
    646             # If a RECORD is received, check for more records

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py in read_message(self)
     94                 chunks.append(self.wire.read(size))
     95         message = b"".join(chunks)
---> 96         _, n = divmod(message[0], 0x10)
     97         try:
     98             unpacker = UnpackStream(message, offset=2)

IndexError: index out of range
```

When I try to change the `relationshipQuery` with oriented path or with an small graph it's works fine.

Running this cypher code directly on neo4j browser it's works and  takes about 80sec to run.

My graph have 10k nodes and 20k relations.

Comment: If it works with Neo4j Browser and not py2neo, then I would suggest creating an issue at https://github.com/py2neo-org/py2neo